# tikz plot change one value of x axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm not so familiar with tikz plot. The plot looks actually like it should, but I would like to change the last position value **300** to **n** in the plot. 
Is this possible ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% for graphs
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=No. of Neihbours,
            ylabel=MAE
            ]   
        \addplot plot coordinates {
                (1,     0.753804)
                (10,    0.759822)
                (25,    0.745213)
                (50,    0.741495)
                (75,    0.743365)
                (100,   0.746219)
                (175,   0.755337)
                (200,   0.758157)
                (300,   0.825300)
        };  

        \legend{$fullcos$\\$d=3$\\$d=4$\\$d=5$\\$d=6$\\}

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi superbly, please could you wrap your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), starting with `\documentclass`. It makes it easier for me to reproduce your situation on my machine.

Comment: You can use `xticklabels={<list of values>}`, as in     `\begin{axis}[
        xlabel=No. of Neighbours,
        ylabel=RSME,
       xticklabels={0,0,50,100,150,200,250,n},
        ]`

Comment: I changed it to a full document. hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo Medina. That was it. Thank you very much. If you make an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @superbly answer added.

Comment: @superbly I added another option to my answer. Now you don't need to give the complete list of labels, and you can change just the last value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to use `xticklabels={<list of values>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=No. of Neighbours,
        ylabel=RSME,
        xticklabels={0,0,50,100,150,200,250,n},
        ]   
    \addplot plot coordinates {
            (1,     1.040923)
            (10,    1.015503)
            (25,    0.947140)
            (50,    0.923818)
            (75,    0.922332)
            (100,   0.925733)
            (175,   0.941590)
            (200,   0.946928)
            (300,   1.064557)
    };  
    \legend{$d=2$\\$d=3$\\$d=4$\\$d=5$\\$d=6$\\}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the list of x labels is too long, the above solution might be cumbersome; here's another approach, allowing to change only the last label, without modifying the previous values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=No. of Neighbours,
        ylabel=RSME,
       every x tick label/.append style={alias=ultick},
       extra description/.append code={
            \fill [white] (ultick.north west) ++(0pt,-2\pgflinewidth) rectangle (ultick.south east);         
            \node [anchor=south] at (ultick.south) {n};}        ]   
    \addplot plot coordinates {
            (1,     1.040923)
            (10,    1.015503)
            (25,    0.947140)
            (50,    0.923818)
            (75,    0.922332)
            (100,   0.925733)
            (175,   0.941590)
            (200,   0.946928)
            (300,   1.064557)
    };  
    \legend{$d=2$\\$d=3$\\$d=4$\\$d=5$\\$d=6$\\}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]